# How can I use the useFetch hook when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a request using useFetch from react-fetch-hook npm package when a button is pressed. Here is my code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import useFetch from 'react-fetch-hook';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Component = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(false);

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    const { isLoading, data } = useFetch(
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmclaren2/sample_json/main/user.json'
    );
    if (isLoading) {
      setMessage('Loading...');
    } else {
      setMessage(`Received id: ${data.id}`);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOnClick}>Load Data</Button>
      <div>{message}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Component;
```

I encountered this error

`React Hook "useFetch" is called in function "handleOnClick" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function.`

What is the correct way to call useFetch when the user presses the button and show the "Loading..." and then the result messages?

Comment: You can't use hooks in functions that are not components or custom hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[useFetch](https://github.com/ilyalesik/react-fetch-hook/blob/master/index.js) is a hooks that wrap global [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) method. It is considered as a custom `React Hook` by `react` because of its [name](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)

> Custom Hooks are more of a convention than a feature. If a function’s name starts with ”use” and it calls other Hooks, we say it is a custom Hook.

So, the placement has to follow react custom hooks rules
whether in a React function component or in a custom React Hook function.

As the [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fetch-hook) says that we can use `depends` options to trigger the fetch.

> The request will not be called until all elements of depends array be truthy.

So, we can implement this by using `isClicked` state as the fetch trigger where the `isClicked` state will be reset by `useEffect` hooks. So, on every click event, the `useFetch` will make a new request to the server'

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-water-hutt9p?file=/src/App.js:0-815)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useFetch from 'react-fetch-hook';

const Component = () => {
   const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
   const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

   // place the useFetch hooks here as the rules says
   const { isLoading, data } = useFetch(
      'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmclaren2/sample_json/main/user.json',
       { depends: [isClicked] }
   );

   useEffect(() => {
      isClicked && setIsClicked(false);
   },[isClicked]);

   useEffect(() => {
      if (isLoading) {
         setMessage('Loading ...');
      }
      if (data && !isLoading) {
         setMessage(`Received id: ${data.id}`)
      }
   },[data, isLoading])

   return (
      <div>
         <button onClick={() => setIsClicked(true)}>Load Data</button>
         <div>{message}</div>
      </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Great answer - but it seems that the simpler approach would be to use the underlying fetch call directly instead of using the useFetch hook

Comment: Thank you Mark. I'm not the creator of the `useFetch` hook, but, to me, custom hooks will help a lot when we write repetitive codes. It reduces the line number of code and helps us implement DRY principle. If you use plain fetch, at some point you will end up creating a reusable code, and in react, custom hooks are one of the applicable approaches to make our code reusable. But again, it depends on individual taste.

Comment: I think the useFetch hook only makes the code simple if the data is to be fetched at the time the component is loaded.  If the data is loaded later (eg. when the user clicks a button) then this useFetch hook makes the code more confusing

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe do something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import useFetch from "react-fetch-hook";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

export default function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  const {
    isLoading,
    data
  } = useFetch(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markmclaren2/sample_json/main/user.json",
    { depends: [isClicked], formatter: (response) => response.text() }
  );

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
    if (isLoading) {
      setMessage("Loading...");
    } else {
      setMessage(data as string);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOnClick}>Load Data</Button>
      <div>{message}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also prepared a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-https-v0tcxo?file=/src/App.tsx:0-754) here so you can check it out

Comment: When I run this code I have to press the button twice before I see the output